# Deleted questions not removed from homepage on "New Activity" notification

Tags: bug, deleted-questions

Upon the homepage, if a question is deleted, and another triggers the "New activity" notification, which is then clicked on, the deleted posts are not removed from the list while bumped ones are added. Is this a bug? Please comment if you need more details.